# Cumulative sum of a qualitative variable in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to compute a graph that tells me the increasing nº of species I am recording thorugh time, preferably with `ggplot` and `geom_line`. So it would be something like: the first day I had one species, day 1 equals 1 species. 2nd day I detected 2 new species, day 2 should equal 3 species. If on day 5 I detected another new species, day five should equal 4 species, and so on.

It's probably an easy thing but couldn't find the way to an example within the forum, probably because I am not using the right words. What I would like from my data would be something like (don't take numbers as reference, my total number of species is only 15, no 52 like in this plot!):

[image]

You can use this subset of my dataset as a reproducible example:

```
dataset <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18496, 18496, 18497, 18497, 
18498, 18498, 18498, 18499, 18499, 18500, 18501, 18504, 18505, 
18505, 18506, 18506, 18506, 18506, 18506, 18507, 18507, 18507, 
18507, 18507, 18509, 18483, 18484, 18484, 18486, 18486, 18487, 
18487, 18488, 18488, 18489, 18490, 18490, 18492, 18493, 18494, 
18519, 18519, 18520, 18518, 18518, 18518, 18496, 18496, 18496, 
18499, 18500, 18501, 18504, 18506, 18506, 18506, 18506, 18508, 
18484, 18486, 18490, 18491, 18491, 18492, 18494, 18495, 18482, 
18484, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18486, 18496, 18498, 18499, 18501, 
18504, 18505, 18507, 18507, 18509, 18482, 18483, 18484, 18486, 
18487, 18488, 18488, 18488, 18489, 18489, 18490, 18492, 18493, 
18495, 18498, 18499, 18504, 18504, 18504, 18505, 18505, 18506, 
18506, 18507, 18507, 18507, 18507), class = "Date"), speciesname = c("Grey Heron", 
"Grey Heron", "Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", "Green Sandpiper", 
"Grey Heron", "Greater Flamingo", "Grey Heron", "Night Heron", 
"Night Heron", "Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", "Common Sandpiper", 
"Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", 
"Dotterel", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Ortolan Bunting", "Ortolan Bunting", 
"Spotted Flycatcher", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", 
"Nightjar", "Grey Heron", "Green Sandpiper", "Common Sandpiper", 
"Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Snipe", "Common Sandpiper", 
"Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", "Night Heron", "Dunlin", "Snipe", 
"Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", 
"Night Heron", "Night Heron", "Grey Heron", "Green Sandpiper", 
"Robin", "Green Sandpiper", "Ortolan Bunting", "Grey Heron", 
"Dotterel", "Whimbrel", "Dotterel", "Grey Heron", "Common Sandpiper", 
"Grey Heron", "Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", "Night Heron", 
"Night Heron", "Green Sandpiper", "Little Bittern", "Grey Heron", 
"Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Night Heron", 
"Grey Heron", "Ortolan Bunting", "Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", 
"Night Heron", "Night Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", 
"Grey Heron", "Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", 
"Grey Heron", "Western Swamphen", "Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", 
"Night Heron", "Grey Heron", "Whimbrel", "Greater Flamingo", 
"Night Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", "Grey Heron", 
"Night Heron", "Ortolan Bunting", "Night Heron", "Night Heron", 
"Night Heron", "Common Sandpiper", "Grey Heron", "Night Heron", 
"Grey Heron", "Night Heron", "Grey Heron")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -108L))
```

**Thanks a lot!!**

Comment: I think other guys are misguided by the plot. Moreover they want to publish their results as fast as possible so do not see what you wrote there. For me your question is very precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R with env as dict:

```r
dataset <- dataset[order(dataset$date),]

finda <- new.env() #as map/dict
dataset$speciesname_u <- 0
cc <- 0

for (i in seq_len(nrow(dataset))) {
  ss <- as.character(dataset[i, "speciesname"])
  if (ss %in% ls(finda)) {
    dataset[i, "speciesname_u"] <- cc
  } else {
    finda[[ss]] <- NULL
    cc <- cc + 1
    dataset[i, "speciesname_u"] <- cc
  }
}

dataset$date <- lubridate::ymd(dataset$date)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = date, y = speciesname_u)) + geom_line() + geom_point() +
    scale_x_date(date_labels="%d-%b-%Y",breaks = '10 days') +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
#or aggragating by day and take the maximum 
library(dplyr)
ggplot(dataset %>% group_by(date) %>% mutate(spec_u = max(speciesname_u)) %>% ungroup(), aes(x = date, y = spec_u)) + geom_line() + geom_point() +
    scale_x_date(date_labels="%d-%b-%Y",breaks = '10 days') +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. Your first can use `dplyr` functions to count the number of species by each day and after that you can compute the cumulative sum by day using `cum()` with `mutate()`. The good thing is that you can integrate all the process in one pipeline with `dplyr` and `ggplot2`. Here the code using the data you provided:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Code for data process
dataset %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  #Compute number of species across days
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Cum=cumsum(N)) %>%
  #Plot
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=Cum,group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%d-%m-%Y",breaks = '3 days',expand = c(0.01,0))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Output:

[image]

And if more customization is needed:

```
#Code for data process 2
dataset %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  #Compute number of species across days
  summarise(N=n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Cum=cumsum(N)) %>%
  #Plot
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=Cum,group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%d-%b-%Y",breaks = '3 days',expand = c(0.01,0))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))+
  ylab('Cumulative number of species discovered in XYZ place')
```

Output:

[image]

For unique number of species each day we can use `n_distinct()`:

```
#Code for data process 3
dataset %>% 
  group_by(date) %>%
  #Compute number of species across days
  summarise(N=n_distinct(speciesname)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Cum=cumsum(N)) %>%
  #Plot
  ggplot(aes(x=date,y=Cum,group=1))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%d-%b-%Y",breaks = '3 days',expand = c(0.01,0))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'))+
  ylab('Cumulative number of species discovered in XYZ place')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is a better solution than mine (I completely missed the point)

Comment: Thanks Duck for your answer! It looks nice. The only thing is that I am not certain about what your function is adding. At date = 0 species should be 0, and by the end of the period species should equal to 15, not 100 something. Thanks again!

Comment: Do not worry Robin! Thanks anyway. It's hard to explain what I am looking for... It would be a graph to tell me the number of species I have detected though time. So the first day I had one, and if on the 2nd day I detected 2 new species, day 2 should equal 3. Hope I explain myself better this time!

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo Hi dear, as you wanted the cumulative sum, what I did is grouping by day and computing the number of species you had each day, after day you accumulate that value and then plot! Do you need another thing?

Comment: Sorry Duck, I think my question was quite confusing with the word frequency in it... So it would be: a graph to tell me the number of species I have detected though time. So the first day I had one species, and if on the 2nd day I detected 2 new species, day 2 should equal 3. If on day 5 I detected another new species, day five should equal 4, and so on.

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo Understood now, I will add an update now!

Comment: Thanks a lot Duck! sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo I have added un update in the final part of the post, it counts the number of unique species each day and then compute cum sum and plot!

Comment: @OriolBaenaCrespo I hope that can be helpful!

Comment: Sorry Duck again, but maybe I didn't explain myself well again... :( I think what I need is much more simple than thing you are understanding, and it because I am misusing the word cumulative. The graph should range on the y axis from 0 (day 0 I haven't seen any bird species) to 15 (which is the total number of different species I have seen during all the time period). If you have any suggestion on how should I ask my question to get a proper answer I will modify post's title. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the cumulative sum of each species then you can do this:-

```
df<-dataset%>%
  group_by(date, speciesname)%>%
  summarise(number_of_species=n())


df<-mutate(group_by(df,speciesname), cumsum=cumsum(number_of_species))



# A tibble: 67 x 4
# Groups:   speciesname [15]
   date       speciesname      number_of_species cumsum
   <date>     <chr>                        <int>  <int>
 1 2020-08-08 Common Sandpiper                 1      1
 2 2020-08-08 Grey Heron                       1      1
 3 2020-08-09 Grey Heron                       2      3
 4 2020-08-10 Common Sandpiper                 2      3
 5 2020-08-10 Grey Heron                       2      5
 6 2020-08-10 Nightjar                         1      1
 7 2020-08-12 Green Sandpiper                  1      1
 8 2020-08-12 Grey Heron                       6     11
 9 2020-08-12 Night Heron                      1      1
10 2020-08-13 Common Sandpiper                 1      4
```

Then time to plot:-

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date,y=cumsum, group=speciesname,colour=speciesname))+geom_line()+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Cumulative sum of species", subtitle = "From 08/08/2020 to 15/09/2020")
```

Which can give you this:-

[image]